# Stop text from "jiggling" when updating

Tags: javascript

I am updating the `textContent` in an element so I can give the impression that a score is increasing. However, when I do this, the entire text field seems to 'jiggle', as it appears to be centre justified. I want to use a variable field width font. You can see this behaviour by running the below. Feel free to recommend any style changes as well.  The goal is to have the text anchored and not 'jiggle'.

```js
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 300, true, true);

function myCallback(effects, updateScore) {

  var elementId = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
  var elementName = "element" + elementId;
  var location = getLocation();
  var textAndScore = getTextAndScore();
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.style.position = "absolute";
  elem.style.left = location.left + "px";
  elem.style.top = location.top + "px";
  elem.name = elementName;
  elem.setAttribute("points", textAndScore.score);
  setStyle(elem, textAndScore.text, textAndScore.score);
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.id = elementName;
  var it = "#" + elem.id;
  console.log(it);

  if (effects) {
    addEffects(it);
    window.setTimeout(removeTextCallback, 5000, it);
    window.setInterval(updateText, 50, elem)
  }
  return elem
}

function setStyle(elem, actionText, score) {
  elem.actionText = actionText;
  var scale = Math.random() * 3 + 0.8;
  elem.color = "ff00000";
  elem.style.scale = scale;
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.toUpperCase();
}

function getTextAndScore() {
  return {
    text: "text",
    score: parseFloat("1.00")
  };
}

function getLocation() {
  var foundElem = {
    name: "x"
  }
  while (foundElem.name != undefined) {
    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth);
    var top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight);
    console.log(left, top);
    var foundElem = document.elementFromPoint(left, top);
  }
  console.log(foundElem);
  return {
    left: left,
    top: top
  }
}

function addEffects(it) {
  $(it).fadeIn(1000, "linear");
  $(it).fadeOut(4300, "linear");
}

function updateText(elem) {
  var separator = "+"
  var x = -1.23
  score = (elem.getAttribute("points") - x).toFixed(2)
  elem.setAttribute("points", score)
  elem.textContent = elem.actionText + ": " + separator + score
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.toUpperCase()
}

function removeTextCallback(id) {
  console.log("Removing " + id)
  $(id).remove()
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Mukta', serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta">
```

Comment: The font you are using does not have fixed-width digits. Try one that does. This is an important feature of fonts used for things like score (and a personal peeve is AAA games that feature fonts without fixed-width digits for their scores, resulting in it shifting by a pixel or two when the score changes...)

Comment: `jquery-1.10.2.js`: **Danger**: jQuery 1.x and 2.x are beyond end of life and do no receive security updates. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: It is important (from a style point of view) that the text part is variable width. I did put that in the original question. I will use a more recent jquery version though - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have just the text fixed, you could instead of creating a `div` a more complex container with "pretty" text and monospaced numbers. You have to add another container into the div to seperate the styles apart.

```js
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 300, true, true);

        function myCallback(effects, updateScore) {

            var elementId = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
            var elementName = "element" + elementId;
            var location = getLocation();
            var textAndScore = getTextAndScore();
            var elem = document.createElement("div");
            elem.style.position = "absolute";
            elem.style.left = location.left + "px";
            elem.style.top = location.top + "px";
            elem.name = elementName;
            elem.setAttribute("points", textAndScore.score);
            setStyle(elem, textAndScore.text, textAndScore.score);
            document.body.appendChild(elem);
            elem.id = elementName;
            var it = "#" + elem.id;
            // console.log(it);

            if (effects) {
                addEffects(it);
                window.setTimeout(removeTextCallback, 5000, it);
                window.setInterval(updateText, 50, elem)
            }
            return elem
        }

        function setStyle(elem, actionText, score) {
            elem.actionText = actionText;
            var scale = Math.random() * 3 + 0.8;
            elem.color = "ff00000";
            elem.style.scale = scale;
            elem.textContent = elem.textContent.toUpperCase();
        }

        function getTextAndScore() {
            return {text: "text", score: parseFloat("1.00")};
        }

        function getLocation() {
            var foundElem = {
                name: "x"
            }
            while (foundElem != null && foundElem.name != undefined) { // added foundElement check
                var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
                var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;
                var left = Math.round(Math.random() * fullWidth);
                var top = Math.round(Math.random() * fullHeight);
                // console.log(left, top);
                var foundElem = document.elementFromPoint(left, top);
            }
            // console.log(foundElem);
            return {left: left, top: top}
        }

        function addEffects(it) {
            $(it).fadeIn(1000, "linear");
            $(it).fadeOut(4300, "linear");
        }

        function updateText(elem) {
            var separator = "+"
            var x = -1.23
            score = (elem.getAttribute("points") - x).toFixed(2)
            elem.setAttribute("points", score)
            elem.textContent = elem.actionText + ": " + separator + score
            elem.textContent = elem.textContent.toUpperCase()
        }

        function removeTextCallback(id) {
            // console.log("Removing " + id)
            $(id).remove()
        }
```

```css
body {
  /* font-family: 'Mukta', serif; */
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', serif; /* Added Monospace Font */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta">
```